# Images not showing in code written in HTML

Tags: html, image, filepath

I want to show four different images shown in an html file and im using the "source/file" method and they are not showing. Just shows the broken image sign.

```
<html> 
   <head> 
       <title> Insertar imágenes en una web </title> 
       <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   </head>
   <body> 
       <p>Imagen de una boda</p> 
       <img src="Asignaciones%2520de%2520informatica/boda.jpg"> 
       <p>Imagen de un mercado</p>
       <img src="Asignaciones%2520de%2520informatica/mercado.jpg"> 
       <p>Imagen de una atleta</p> 
       <img src="Asignaciones%2520de%2520informatica/ronaldinho.jpg"> 
       <p>Imagen de un atardecer</p>
       <img src="Asignaciones%2520de%2520informatica/atardecer.jpg"> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: refer the path correctly so that system can able to locate your images to load. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp would be a good place for you to check with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the path of the image on your system is in a directory accessible to the html. Make sure the path is correct and the name of the image is correct.

Comment: Yup this was it. Whenever i pressed Control+S in Brackets to save the code, it saved it outside of the folder. Thanks!

Comment: @javierlora I would appreciate you accepting the answer by pressing the tick mark button. Thanks in advance!